# Почему рекомендуют использовать только GET и POST запросы?

Tags: api, rest, методы

Услышал, что рекомендованно использовать только GET и POST запросы. А если нужно, например удалить, это уже прописывать в теле запроса с методом POST например. Так вот, почему лучше не пользоваться другими методами, и как надо прописывать, что post на самом деле удаляет?

И еще вопрос по кодам ответа. Действительно ли лучше не подбирать подходящий ответ на ошибку, а везде возвращать 200 и описывать, что пошло не так?

Comment: Странно, мне доводилось читать полностью противоположные рекомендации

Comment: "почему лучше не пользоваться другими методами" --- это вы спросите тех, кто рекомендует использовать только GET И POST..... ................ "лучше не подбирать подходящий ответ на ошибку, а везде возвращать 200 и описывать, что пошло не так?" --- как с командой решите. статусы ответов порой нужны для обработки ответа..... а можно статус писать и как значение в поле, например "statusCode"   результирующего объекта...тут, так скажем, много разных факторов, которые могут повлиять на выбираемый способ

Comment: По второй части - например, если сервис вернул код ошибки 404, это может трактоваться, и как то что в URL запроса ошибка (такого энд-поинта не существует), и как то, что запрашиваемого объекта не существует. Это не очень удобно, удобнее использовать свои способы сигнализаии об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Я не отношусь к этим людям, но причина есть. Дело в том что просто html не поддерживает другие методы (да, можно фреймворками менять хитро методы, но всё же). А с кодами - по разному, зависит от людей.

Comment: Что это за бред про html? Вы html'ом собираетесь отправлять запросы на API?

Comment: так я и сказал, что "Я не отношусь к этим людям", и возможно некоторые из-за этого говорят так из за что в html-формах нету других методов, возможно не так выразился)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему бред? Если хочеться чтобы сайт работал без JS, для общения с API остаются только HTML формы, а они только GET и POST поддерживают.

Comment: ну всё таки с api по html'лу как минимум странно. Иногда надо чтобы запрос вообще без пользователя отправился.

Comment: @eanmos без js. вы это сейчас из 2000-го пишите? или 19XX ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский фтопку js, нормальные сайты должны оставаться полностью (или хотя бы почти полностью) работоспособны при отключенном js

Comment: @andreymal да, да, я помню тот сайт mtfkwebsite)))